# Web scraping the content inside nested shadow root using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, shadow-dom

I am trying to scrape the link for CVS store, and found it is inside nested shadow root. I tried a couple of methods and it didn't work.

I would like to get the link of that 'store detail' button from https://www.cvs.com/store-locator/landing?address=446%20SABATTUS%20ST%20LEWISTON,%20ME%2004240.

[image]

I tried:

```
link = "https://www.cvs.com/store-locator/landing?address=446%20SABATTUS%20ST%20LEWISTON,%20ME%2004240"
service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
shadow = Shadow(driver)
z = shadow.chrome_driver.get(link)
element = shadow.find_element("a")
text = element.text
```

But got back nothing.

I also found a method like grabbing CSS_SELECTOR with id, but in my case, this element doesn't have id, so what should I put:

```
def test_shadow_root():
    options =webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(link)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    shadow_text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[id="shadow_content"]').text
    print(shadow_text)
```